# jqgrid getting error when grid is getting loaded

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, mvcjqgrid

Jqgrid is able to load the data. But, gviing error when it getting loaded.

Error is at below lin in - jqgrid min version:

`k=b.jgrid.formatter.integer||{}`
saying `unable to get property of undefined null reference`

Layout has included script file as follow:

```
     <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jqgrid/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jqgrid/i18n/grid.locale-en.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jqgrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Please help me I m just stuck. and spent 3 hours...

I google and found many link where it syas, locale is not  added or add it on first line.. but still not got success.

```
            $('#CategoriesGrdList').jqGrid({
            ajaxGridOptions: {
                error: function () {
                    $('#CategoriesGrdList')[0].grid.hDiv.loading = false;
                    alert('An error has occurred.');
                }
            },
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAllCategoriesList", "Categories")/' + 0,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            //public JsonResult GetEnrolls(int adClassSchedID,DateTime attendanceDate,int adProgramID,int syCampusID)
            postData: { categoryId: 1 },
            //postData: { categoryId: rowID, attendanceDate: $('#AttendanceDate').val(), adProgramID: $('#adProgramID').val(), syCampusID: $('#syCampusID').val() },
            datatype: 'json',
            jsonReader: { root: 'List', page: 'Page', total: 'TotalPages', records: 'TotalCount', repeatitems: false, id: 'Id' },
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Id', 'Code', 'Description', 'IsActive'],
            colModel: [
                  { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', hidden: true },
                { name: 'Code', index: 'Code', width: 170 },
                { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', width: 170 },
            { name: 'IsActive', index: 'IsActive', width: 170 }
            ],
            pager: $('#CategoriesGrdPager'),
            sortname: 'Code',
            rowNum: 40,
            rowList: [3, 3, 3],
            width: '525',
            height: '100%',
            viewrecords: true,

            beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
                return false;

            },
            sortorder: 'desc'
        }).navGrid('#CategoriesGrdPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: What was the reason of your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should always use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` in case of some error inside of jqGrid.

I suppose that the reason of the error is missing `grid.locale-en.js` or other language specific file from `i18n` folder. The language file should be included **before** `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. You should validate whether `grid.locale-en.js` is *really loaded*. Undefined `$.jgrid.formatter` could means only missing `grid.locale-en.js` (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js)).

I recommend you to compare your HTML file (especially `<head>` part) with [the demo HTML file](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#html_file) from the jqGrid documentation.